# Data interoperability json refresh

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geodjango, json, data-interoperability

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 with the data interoperability extension. I am also building a web app using python, django and django-rest-framework. I'm building a json api that i can add to arcmap using data interop. but i can't figure out how to get arcmap/catalog to dump the cached json file it downloads and replace it with an updated version (as i change the api output). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You can clear the Data interoperability cache by clicking "Clear Cache" found under the Data Interoperability tab in ArcMap Options:

Customize -> ArcMap Options -> Data Interoperability tab -> Clear Cache